# Erro ao comparar Array em IF

Tags: ruby

Esse é meu código

```
v3 = []
w=j=k=0
puts "Digite o tamanho do vetor 1"
m = gets.to_i
v1 = Array.new(m)
puts "Digite o tamanho do vetor 2"
n = gets.to_i
v2 = Array.new(m)

for i in 0..m-1
    puts "Digite os valores do vetor 1: "
    v1.push(gets.to_i)
end
for i in 0..n-1
    puts "Digite os valores do vetor 2: "
    v2.push(gets.to_i)
end

while w <= m+n-1
    if (v1[j] < v2[k])
        v3.push(v1[j])
        j += 1
    elsif (v1[j] = v2[k])
        v3.push(v1[j])
        j = j +1
        k = k +1
    else
        v3.push(v2[k])
        k = k +1
    end
    w+=1
end
```

porém ele da erro quando comparo `v1[j] < v2[k]`

Erro retornado:

> ```
> :20:in `<main>': undefined method `<' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Da forma que está criando os arrays

```
Array.new(5)
```

ele retorna um array com 5 posições com valores `nil`.

```
[nil, nil, nil, nil, nil]
```

Basta criar os arrays v1, v2 apenas atribuindo `[]` as variáveis v1, v2

```
v1 = []
v2 = []
```